# hardware agnostic (GPU/CPU) sparse linear algebra C++ solvers framework/technology

Tags: linear-solver, gpu

I am looking for recommendations on matured C++ solver for Linear Sparse Algebra problems.
The goal is to select between more or less GPU hardware agnostic libraries/frameworks that can be compiled on both Linux and Windows with quite high control on host-device memory.
My current research narrows down to the following candidates:

- CUDA - matured, more than BLAS, cross platform, run on NVIDIA only
- OpenCL - matured, competitor to CUDA
- HIP - less matured, but picks lot from CUDA, runs on both NVIDIA & AMD too, no cost on porting between OpenCL and CUDA
- Intel One API (DPC++) - implements [SYCL](https://www.khronos.org/sycl/), seems to be only MKL/LAPACK wrapper now, not sure how it works with GPU system, since MKL is more CPU-centric - seems immature
- Magma - matured, looks like big competitor to CUDA, smaller community

I am close to start with CUDA, since it has a lot of examples in the toolkit, and then potentially migrate to HIP (with [hipify](https://github.com/ROCm-Developer-Tools/HIPIFY)) or to Intel's DPC++ SYCL [guide](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/oneapi-programming-guide/top/software-development-process/migrating-code-to-dpc/migrating-from-cuda-to-dpc.html).

Do you have a link/article/opinion that will help me in challenging these considerations?

Comment: Maybe you do not have much choice about this but I was actually under the impression that sparse solvers on GPUs really have no advantage over CPUs.  Has this changed?

Comment: [Ginkgo](https://ginkgo-project.github.io/) is another library that provides sparse, iterative solvers with backends for OpenMP, CUDA, HIP, and DPC++.

Comment: @KyleMandli Current GPUs have high memory bandwidth compared to CPUs.  So, they perform really well for sparse, iterative solvers.  I don't know how they do for sparse-direct solvers though.

Comment: @NeilLindquist Good point although I assume this gets difficult when you go to multi-node types of setups?

Comment: @KyleMandli I think the difficulties for multi-node are similar between GPU and CPU systems for iterative solvers.  Just call GPU kernels instead of CPU kernels and do host-device memcpy's before/after the MPI calls (or use CUDA-aware MPI). But, I haven't worked with any distributed, GPU-accelerated, sparse codes, so there might be details I'm unaware of.